# Passing ID to API react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass an id using useParam to an api call , when i console.log the id it will show correctly yet when it's in my api if becomes `[object%20Object]`
[image]

VesselComponents.js :

```
function VesselComponents() {
  const vesselId = useParams();
  console.log(vesselId);
  const api = async (vesselId) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        // here
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${vesselId}`
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  const { components, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.components
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchComponents(api(vesselId))(dispatch);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems) => {
    return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
      let children = undefined;
      if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
        children = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
      }
      return (
        <TreeItem
          component={Link}
          to={`./info/${treeItemData.id}`}
          key={treeItemData.id}
          nodeId={String(treeItemData.id)}
          label={treeItemData.name}
          children={children}
        />
      );
    });
  };
  const DataTreeView = ({ treeItems }) => {
    return (
      <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      >
        {getTreeItemsFromData(treeItems)}
      </TreeView>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="components-container">
      <div className="components-items">
        <DataTreeView treeItems={components} />
      </div>
      <div className="component-detail">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VesselComponents;
```

the slice which contains the fetchComponents
ComponentsSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import api from "../components/screen/maintenance/VesselComponents";
export const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: false,
  components: [],
};

const componentsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "components",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLoading: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    setComponents: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
      state.components = payload;
    },
    setError: (state) => {
      state.error = true;
    },
  },
});

export const { setLoading, setComponents, setError } = componentsSlice.actions;

export const componentsSelector = (state) => state.items;
export default componentsSlice.reducer;

// fetch all components
export const fetchComponents = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await api().then((data) => dispatch(setComponents(data)));
  } catch (e) {
    return dispatch(setError());
  }
};
```

Also what is an easier or let's say better way to do this? if i made my call in the slice it self then how can i send the VesselID and simplfy things ?

Comment: `vesselId` is the whole object `useParams` returns, which is serialised to `[object Object]`. Did you want one ID from the parameters? All query parameters back to a `?foo=bar`-type string?

Comment: I want just one id say the url looks like this (http://localhost:3000/maintenance/1/components) i want the number 1 id which reflects current vessel i am in

Comment: Then you probably want `const params = useParams()` followed by `params.<something>`, or use destructuring as shown below.

Comment: With `const vesselId = useParams();` `vesselId` is the entire params object. You are passing the object directly into the URL request. You likely meant to destructure the `id` route param instead, i.e. `const { id } = useParams();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell which Id is i.e:

```
const { id: idDefault = '-1' } = useParams();
```

Try to console vesselId and see what properties it has.

Comment: that did clear the error but API doesn't bring the data could the issue rather be in my slice?

Comment: Check if you get the request on the API, and then you have to check if you are getting any response from the API